# Managing myriad package repositories

Tags: apt, yum, package-management, repository

On testing, development, and some other server and workstation environments, I use a variety of package repositories (with CentOS, for example, these include: [remi](http://blog.famillecollet.com/pages/Config-en), [epel](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), [rpmforge](http://rpmrepo.org/RPMforge), [jpackage](http://www.jpackage.org/yum.php), and others).

Outside of manually installing the repo headers for [yum](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Yum) or [apt](http://wiki.debian.org/Apt), what decent tools exist for managing the use of several (sometimes conflicting/overlapping) package repositories?

For various reasons, I maintain several versions of CentOS, Ubuntu, etc - and being able to draw from any of those repositories is handy.

However, the overhead of managing which ones are available where is a huge pain once you exceed a couple machines.

Would it be worth the energy, space, and time to maintain a full mirror of those repos into a central, localised point where my systems can all go look? If not, what other viable option(s) are there?

---

<sup><sub>Related questions: [tools for maintaining](https://serverfault.com/questions/38813/tools-for-maintaining-yum-repositories), [repositories for centos](https://serverfault.com/questions/203295/repositories-for-centos-that-dont-suck), [decent repositories for centos/fedora](https://serverfault.com/questions/14370/is-there-any-decent-repositories-for-centos-or-fedora)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could mirror the packages that are interesting for your environment and build your own repos out of that.

If you use yum-priorities you can say what repos should be considered first. There is a good howto about that at the CentOS page - I think it was even in the FAQ about rpmforge there.

What I do additionally on my admin workstation is to have the repo metadata installed in /etc/yum.repos.d/, but disable the repo. If I search something new I manually activate the repository on the command line during a search query.

And yes - it makes sense to mirror locally if you have multiple servers that need these repositories - especially if those servers are not connected to the internet themselves.